# I would like to know how to check DatabaseConnections using aws cli.?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to know how to check `DatabaseConnections` using `AWS cli`. Where if connections reaches 50 percent any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get from data point from AWS [get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html#get-metric-statistics)

Then sum the each average to find total average.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace 'AWS/RDS' --metric-name 'DatabaseConnections' --start-time '2020-07-02T12:00:00Z' --end-time '2020-07-02T12:30:00Z'  --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=goabodeprod-us-west-2b --period 60 --statistics Average | \
jq '.Datapoints[].Average' | \
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }'
```

Output

```
719.667
```

[MonitoringOverview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html)